# Como não executar as linhas de código quando o nome não está na lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa noite! Estou iniciando na programação Python. 
Tenho esse exercício (livro) que alterei para ter mais interação com usuário. 
Quando inserimos uma string que não está na lista, apresenta o 'cardápio'. 
Como faço para executar somente a mensagem "Desculpe, seu nome...." e não apresentar o 'cardápio' para essa string que está fora da lista.

```
 lista_convidados = ['arthur', 'maria', 'roberto', 'naime', 'letícia']

cardapio = ['lasanha', 'hamburguer', 'fritas', 'picanha', 'feijoada', 'bisteca']

pergunta = input('Boa noite SR(a), informe seu nome: ')

resposta = pergunta.lower()

for nome in lista_convidados:
    if resposta == nome:
        print(f'Seja bem-vindo {resposta.title()}, entre e faça seu pedido.\n ')
        break

else:
    print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, seu nome não está na lista.\n'
        f'Obrigado pela a preferência, VOLTE SEMPRE!\n')



# Cliente pode escolher o prato desejado.

print("********** C A R D Á P I O **********\n")

for menu in cardapio:
    if menu in cardapio:
        print(f'{menu.title()}: ')

print("\n*************************************")

pedido_menu = input('\nDigite o prato desejado: ')

resposta_menu = pedido_menu.lower()

for escolha in cardapio:

    if resposta_menu == escolha:
        print(f'Ótima escolha, a {resposta_menu.title()} está deliciosa!')
        break

else:
    print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, não estamos servindo esse prato hoje.\n'
          f'OBRIGADO PELA PREFERÊNCIA, VOLTE SEMPRE!')
```

Answer (score 3):

**Dica para melhorar o código: ( Operador "in" )**

Primeiro de tudo, você pode verificar se o nome está na lista de convidados utilizando o operador `in`, não sendo necessário verificar elemento por elemento com o *for loop*. Exemplo:

```
lista_convidados = ['arthur', 'maria', 'roberto', 'naime', 'letícia']
cardapio = ['lasanha', 'hamburguer', 'fritas', 'picanha', 'feijoada', 'bisteca']

nome = input('Boa noite SR(a), informe seu nome: ').lower()

if nome in lista_convidados:
    print(f'Seja bem-vindo {nome.title()}, entre e faça seu pedido.\n ')

else:
    print(f'Desculpe {nome.title()}, seu nome não está na lista.\n'
        f'Obrigado pela a preferência, VOLTE SEMPRE!\n')
```

---

**Encerrando o programa caso o usuário não esteja na lista: ( Funções quit e sys.exit )**

Agora em relação a não apresentar o cardápio para quem não é convidado, você pode utilizar a função `quit()`. Essa função irá encerrar a execução do seu programa e pode ser usada caso queira que seu programa acabe para o usuário que não está na lista. Exemplo:

```
for nome in lista_convidados:
    if resposta == nome:
        print(f'Seja bem-vindo {resposta.title()}, entre e faça seu pedido.\n ')
        break

else:
    print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, seu nome não está na lista.\n'
        f'Obrigado pela a preferência, VOLTE SEMPRE!\n')
    quit()
```

---

Uma outra função que você pode utilizar é o `sys.exit(status)`. Ele faz a mesma coisa que o `quit()` porém ele retorna um código ao fechar o programa. Exemplo:

```
import sys

# ...

for nome in lista_convidados:
        if resposta == nome:
            print(f'Seja bem-vindo {resposta.title()}, entre e faça seu pedido.\n ')
            break

else:
    print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, seu nome não está na lista.\n'
        f'Obrigado pela a preferência, VOLTE SEMPRE!\n')
    sys.exit(17) # Código de exemplo: 17 significa que o cliente não está na lista.
```

---

**Apresentando o cardápio apenas ao cliente que está na lista: ( Criando funções )**

Se você deseja prosseguir com seu programa sem que o usuário tenha acesso ao cardápio, você pode isolar o seu código de cardápio dentro do bloco `if` ou criar um função para mostrar o cardápio apenas para quem está na lista de convidados. Exemplo:

```
def mostraCardapio(cardapio):
    """
    Função para mostrar o cardápio e obter pedido do cliente.
    """

    print("********** C A R D Á P I O **********\n")

    for menu in cardapio:
        print(f'{menu.title()}: ')

    print("\n" + "*" * 37)  # Imprime o asterisco 37 vezes.

    resposta = input('\nDigite o prato desejado: ').lower()

    if resposta in cardapio:
        print(f'Ótima escolha, a {resposta.title()} está deliciosa!')

    else:
        print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, não estamos servindo esse prato hoje.\n'
              f'OBRIGADO PELA PREFERÊNCIA, VOLTE SEMPRE!')



lista_convidados = ['arthur', 'maria', 'roberto', 'naime', 'letícia']
cardapio = ['lasanha', 'hamburguer', 'fritas', 'picanha', 'feijoada', 'bisteca']

nome = input('Boa noite SR(a), informe seu nome: ').lower()

if nome in lista_convidados:
    print(f'Seja bem-vindo {nome.title()}, entre e faça seu pedido.\n ')
    mostraCardapio(cardapio)

else:
    print(f'Desculpe {nome.title()}, seu nome não está na lista.\n'
        f'Obrigado pela a preferência, VOLTE SEMPRE!\n')
```

Como eu disse, você pode isolar o código para mostrar o cardápio dentro do bloco `if` sem criar uma função, porém não ficaria muito bem organizado o seu código. Uma outra vantagem de se criar uma função para mostrar o cardápio, é que você pode chamá-la diversas vezes para que o usuário possar realizar um pedido quantas vezes ele desejar.

Você pode saber mais sobre funções em Python clicando aqui neste [site](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-python-orientacao-objetos/funcoes/#o-que--uma-funo) e para saber mais sobre como criar um código bem organizado, sugiro que dê olhada no assunto [*"Clean Code"*](https://becode.com.br/clean-code/).

Comment: É melhor que se tenha uma função para mostrar o cardápio e outra para perguntar sobre o prato desejado.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Utilizando a forma que explicou consegui aplicar no código. E outras melhorias que não sabia que era possível para deixar o código mais limpo e legível.

Comment: @LucasMaraal De fato, seguindo as boas práticas, nesse código deveria ser criado funções como `verificaCliente`, `mostraCardapio` e `realizaPedido`, porém não fiz isso para não estender tanto a resposta e também para não sair do foco. Sem falar que o @echaves ainda é iniciante, então por enquanto, ele precisa estudar sobre funções e outros para depois pensar em manter o código bem organizado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar fazer algo como:

```
def verifica_cliente(resposta):
    lista_convidados = ['arthur', 'maria', 'roberto', 'naime', 'letícia']

    if resposta in lista_convidados:
        print(f'Seja bem-vindo {resposta.title()}, entre e faça seu pedido.\n ')
        verifica_cardapio(resposta)
    else:
        print(f'\nDesculpe {resposta.title()}, seu nome não está na lista.')
        print(f'Obrigado pela a preferência, VOLTE SEMPRE!\n')


def verifica_cardapio(resposta):
    cardapio = ['lasanha', 'hamburguer', 'fritas', 'picanha', 'feijoada', 'bisteca']
    # Cliente pode escolher o prato desejado.

    print("********** C A R D Á P I O **********\n")
    for menu in cardapio:
        print(f'{menu.title()}: ')

    print("\n*************************************")

    resposta_menu = input('\nDigite o prato desejado: ').lower()

    for escolha in cardapio:
        if resposta_menu == escolha:
            print(f'Ótima escolha {resposta.title()}, a {resposta_menu.title()} está deliciosa!')
            break

        else:
            print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, não estamos servindo esse prato hoje.\n'
                  f'OBRIGADO PELA PREFERÊNCIA, VOLTE SEMPRE!')

resposta = input('Boa noite SR(a), informe seu nome: ').lower()
verifica_cliente(resposta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seu material ainda não apresentou funções, então para você resolver esse exercício seguindo a didátia do livro, você deve trabalhar com o conceito de aninhamento. Não é a melhor abordagem, mas em uma curva de aprendizado faz sentido você fazer dessa forma algumas vezes. Note que usei `sys.exit()` para que o programa termine, se não passarmos nenhum argumento para esta função ela irá encerrar o programa com `exit status` igual a zero, o que significa que o programa terminou com sucesso.

```
import sys 

lista_convidados = ['arthur', 'maria', 'roberto', 'naime', 'letícia']

cardapio = ['lasanha', 'hamburguer', 'fritas', 'picanha', 'feijoada', 'bisteca']

pergunta = input('Boa noite SR(a), informe seu nome: ')

resposta = pergunta.lower()

for nome in lista_convidados:
    if resposta == nome:
        print(f'Seja bem-vindo {resposta.title()}, entre e faça seu pedido.\n ')

        # Cliente pode escolher o prato desejado.

        print("********** C A R D Á P I O **********\n")

        for menu in cardapio:
            if menu in cardapio:
                print(f'{menu.title()}: ')

        print("\n*************************************")

        pedido_menu = input('\nDigite o prato desejado: ')

        resposta_menu = pedido_menu.lower()

        for escolha in cardapio:

            if resposta_menu == escolha:
                print(f'Ótima escolha, a {resposta_menu.title()} está deliciosa!')
                sys.exit() 
            else:
                print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, não estamos servindo esse prato hoje.\n'
                    f'OBRIGADO PELA PREFERÊNCIA, VOLTE SEMPRE!')
                sys.exit() 

print(f'Desculpe {resposta.title()}, seu nome não está na lista.\n'
      f'Obrigado pela a preferência, VOLTE SEMPRE!\n')
```